# location unavailable capacitor ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, gps, capacitor

location unavailable capacitor ionic.we cant access location in android device getting this error messgae.

```
  capacitor-runtime.js:414 {message: "location unavailable"}message: 
  "location 
  unavailable"__proto__: Object
   capacitor.logFromNative @ capacitor-runtime.js:414
   fromNative @ capacitor-runtime.js:212
    (anonymous) @ VM289:1
   pages-add-add-module-es2015.js:186 Error getting location {message: 
 "location unavailable"}
```

Comment: Can you please share your codes/implementation for better understanding?

Answer (score 2):

An android device or an emulator?

If we talk about an android device check the GPS to be enabled, for some phones is not working with this enabled.

On emulator this plugin is not working.

Comment: No I am tested in real device with gps on.

Comment: I can confirm that the plugin is not working with Android Studio Emulator (at least with Pixel 3 Virtual Device, API 29, running Android 10 x86). I've tested the same code on the XCode emulator (IPhone X) and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

for Emulator, you have to set a default location first,

```
go to emulator settings -> Location -> Search for a place(set the marker) -> click 'Set Location'
```

[image]

Then in your component you can do something like :

```
import { Capacitor, Plugins } from "@capacitor/core";
const { Geolocation } = Plugins;  // don't inject in ctor()

Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
      }).then((resp) => {            
        this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
        this.lng = resp.coords.longitude;
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);
      });
```

And to check GPS permission you can use the following

```
isGpsPermissionEnabled(permissions: AndroidPermissions): Promise<boolean> {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (Capacitor.isNative) {
            permissions.checkPermission(permissions.PERMISSION.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).then(
                rs => resolve(rs.hasPermission),
                err => {
                    console.log("something went wrong")
                }
            );
        }
        else { resolve(true); // for browsers
         }
    })
}
```